# Importing Mixamo's FBX in Blender

Tags: animation, import

I'm trying import the character with the animation and it gets scrambled, I tried a lot of settings but in the end, none of them worked. Other editors like Unreal's Engine Editor can import the file without any problems.

The file can be downloaded in here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/i20wfur8e34i3a2/Sword_And_Shield_Slash.fbx?dl=0

Here's what happen when i try to import:
[image: Possible Bug Example]

Comment: Found my .FBX files having this issue on import...unable to acheive a nice import using .FBX. able to import successfully using .dae from Mixamo [Professional Tutorial here](https://community.mixamo.com/hc/en-us/articles/204227123-Tutorial-Auto-Rigging-a-Blender-Character?utm_campaign=1412%20BlenderNation%20Post&utm_medium=Blog&utm_source=BlenderNation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also experienced this weird stuff and I was able to solve it.

- Select the distorted object
- Select Object Tab from Properties Window
- Change Transform scale to 0.01
- Change Transform X-axis to 90 degrees

Result:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1yip15gm13dke1c/COnverted.blend?dl=0

- Option 2: You may refer to this link if you don't want to do it manually. http://growlybearproductions.com/Blender/
- Option 3: You may also change fbx import settings like this (Blender 2.76b)

  [image: Import Settings]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and managed to fix it by doing this. First you need to scale your model correctly to the size you want in Blender Then while in object mode press a to select all and then press "ctrl + a" and apply scale, rotation and location. Then export your model as an .obj Import it into Mixamo animate it and then export it as a .dae. Then import the .dae into blender Re-scale the model to what you had it as before and then it should work